# Shape of an elastic steel ruler bent between 3 pins

Tags: classical-mechanics, forces, elasticity

An thin elastic steel ruler is bent around 3 pins. It's not attached to the pins and can slide freely (not attached to the pins).

Let's assume that the pin coordinates are $(0,0)$, $(x,y)$, $(1,0)$

**What formula can describe the shape of the ruler?**

**What are the formulas for the reaction forces of the pins?

[image]

Comment: This may be useful https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_interpolation

Comment: Is a cubic spline a true shape of the ruler or is it just an approximation?

Comment: I'd try a hyperbola before selecting other shapes.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that the question as it is is ill-posed and has no unique solution (I am not sure what a solution is actually). For instance, one  needs to know what the Lagrangian is (i.e., the elastic potential) as it depends on cross-section/thickness, ... Also, what is the length of the ruler, at which points should it meet the pins and what are the boundary conditions.

So for the sake of giving an answer I made up a couple of hypotheses that suit me: <s>the cows are spherical and live in a vacuum</s> the ruler is infinitely thin and the pins are point-like. The ruler is also inextensible of length $L$ and has a bending energy proportional to the square of its curvature:
$$
E \propto \int_0^L \kappa^2(s) \mathrm d s
$$
where $s$ is the coordinate along the ruler. If $x$ is the position of particle $s$ then
$$
\kappa^2 = \langle\ddot x,\ddot x\rangle = \dot\theta^2
$$
with $\dot x = (\cos \theta,\sin \theta)$ since under the inextensibility constraint $\langle \dot x,\dot x\rangle = 1$. Minimizing $E$ yields the Euler-Lagrange equation (**EDIT**: the following equations were corrected):
$$
2\ddot \theta + \lambda_1 \cos\theta + \lambda_2 \sin\theta = 0
$$
where $\lambda_{1,2}$ are Lagrange multipliers. This can be integrated once after multiplication by $\dot \theta$. **All in all, the equation of the ruler between two pins is given implicitly by**
$$
\int_0^s \frac{\mathrm d\theta}{\sqrt{c-\lambda_1\sin\theta+\lambda_2\cos\theta}} = s.
$$
Therein, $c$ is an integration constant.

Once we have $\theta$ (somehow numerically), we need to integrate once more to get $x$. As for the constants $(c,\lambda_{1,2})$, we need to ensure smoothness across pins and to know at which $s_i$ the ruler goes through the pin at $x_i$. Note that this system may not admit a solution if the positions $x_i$ are too far apart so that inextensibility cannot be ensured.

**EDIT**:
A couple more details. The total length of the ruler does matter. Here is an extreme scenario. If the length of the ruler is infinite, there exists a sequence of configurations parametrized with $R$ such that the bending energy goes to $0$ as $R$ goes to infinity. In that case, a solution that minimizes bending energy does not exist. The buckled shape in the figure should be familiar.[image: buckled ruler] It would help a lot to say for instance that the ruler goes through the first pin at $s_0=0$ and through the third one at $s_3$ = L. As for $s_2$, it can be determined by minimizing bending energy over the reduced set of candidate solutions. But even in these cases, I am not sure that buckling can be completely precluded.

Comment: I think that the solution is unique (given $(x,y)$, cross-section I and elastic constants.).  Length of the ruler should not matter. We can consider it infinite. The ruler is not attached to the pins. It can slide to reduce the bending energy. (Imagine pulling the ruler by the ends to make a sharp bend and then releasing those ends.). So, $L$, $s_i$ are not given. (Or we can say that the ruler is half-infinite and $s_0 = (0,0)$ )

Comment: - Assuming inextensibility, we can prescribe $s_1=0$ and $s_3=L$. As for $s_2$, it can be determined by a second round of minimization.
- If the ruler is infinite or semi-infinite then no minimizing solution exists. See figure in the edited answer.

Comment: Interesting configuration. I think we can easily constrain the problem so that the self-intersections are impossible (as they are in most real-life problems). Also, going from no self-intersection to one would require the material to really go through itself and not just bend around. It'd also have to go through a state with zero curvature radius and infinite bending energy which does not happen naturally.  Still, I thought about the problem more and now I see that there are some "expanding to infinity" configurations that do not require self-intersection.

Comment: If you move $P2 (x,y)$ "high" enough, the pressure on P2 would eventually disappear and after that, the ruler would probably form a forever expanding curve that only touches P1 and P3.

Comment: Still, there is a big area for (x,y) where the finite-length energy minimum exists. When we start from the curve of minimum length ($L_min=|P_2 - P_1| + |P_3 - P_2|$) we have forces with non-zero net effect and they act to reduce the bending energy.  In some configurations (the ones that I'm interested in) there exists a local minimum and the minimum-length curve is in its basin of attraction.

Comment: From the fixed-length perspective: Suppose, we have a stabilized fixed-length curve of length $L$. It has some bending energy $E$. We might try to minimize $E(L)$ by following $dE(L)/dL$. FOr some configurations we'll end up in a local minimum ($dE(L)/dL = 0$) with finite $L$. I'm interested in the shapes associated with those local energy minimums. The math might be easier in those points.